# Gnuplot decimal separator of the input data

Tags: gnuplot, digit-separator

How can I change the decimal separator of the input data for the gnuplot from the default period '.' to the comma ','? As far as I have found, command 'set locale' can be used. However, the problem is to find the locales, available for the gnuplot under Windows.

Comment: Have you tried instead set decimalsign ',' ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it does not work. According to the documentation, "set decimalsign" changes the decimal separators of the axes tics labels only.

Comment: @BorysL. Have you tried for example `set locale "French"` or `set locale "German"`? In case it is available on your system, this should set the _input_ decimal separator to `,`.